# Is it possible to group 2 objects, one in an opacity mask and the other on the artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The reason is that I want to move them anchored together, from within the opacity mask.

Comment: nothing can move artboards other than artboard itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the scenario but a symbol can group a normal object with one which uses an opacity mask

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. An opacity mask isn't selectable as an object.  The object using the mask is the object.  It seems to me like this could be [an XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you show an example image (a screenshot) of what you are actually trying to achieve or what problem you are trying to solve by doing this? There may be a way to achieve what you want using some other technique entirely.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/lq2ySxg.png type 1 are text boxes, type 2 images. Type 1 I made by creating a mask from the black page fill + the stroke. Type 2 I made by creating a mask from the image + the image strokes. My goal was to have type 1 mask as sufficient also for the image reveal. And it is, except that I cannot move the type 1 stroke together with the image cause they are in artboard vs mask. Transparent text boxes? Yes, so that I can change their color also after imported it into InDesign. But now I will do the whole thing only in Illustrator and export it as Press PDF, it's a magazine.

Comment: the xyproblem example  is not grammatically correct, the last 3 characters in a filename are before the dot that is is before the extension, so they are not part of the file name - that renders the example useless

Comment: Adam, you've missed the point of Billy's X/Y link. It's meant to show how the user *thinks* the problem is X.. but in *actuality* the problem is Y and the user *doesn't know* that Y is the problem and hasn't even thought of Y. However, if Y is corrected, then X is no longer an issue.

Comment: But my question is still valid: if I only use brush 1 / mask 1, for the image reveal too, how do I move the image and the brush strokes that reveal the image, anchored together?

Comment: You are thinking backwards.. one does **not** punch a bunch of holes in a black background. You place white (or light colored objects) **on top** of the black background. If you are drawing on a chalkboard.. you don't need to make holes in the chalkboard. The chalk is lighter so it shows up on the dark background. And Yes, the question is valid I've answered it below.

Comment: The holes I needed so that I can change the text box color within Indesign, if imported from Illustrator. But now I will do everything in Illustrator, so for that part I will just brush and put the text on it. Okay, so you cannot move an object in a mask and an image on the artboard anchored or grouped together, unless you release tha mask. But then you have to recreate the mask. Just wanted to make sure that I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.
<sub>(You may be aware of much of the below. I included some explanation for any future visitor who may not be familiar with Opacity Mask operations.)</sub>

---

**TL;DR:** You **can not** move an object's **Opacity Mask** *and* some other, unassociated, object while keeping the masked object in its current position.

And you can **not** "group" an opacity mask with anything other than the object it is *applied to*. The mask ***only exists*** for object(s) it is masking.

---

**Opacity Masks** *aren't* seen as normal objects on any artboard.

Opacity Masks exist in a sort of "isolation area" for the object(s) they are masking, not as normal artboard objects. They are seen as being *part of the object they are masking*.

So.... if your artboard contains a rectangle and a circle, and the circle has an opacity mask applied to it.

- If the opacity mask is **linked** to its parent object (the circle)... 
  [image] 
   ...moving the circle will *also* move its associated opacity mask. The circle's appearance will *remain the same* as the circle's position changes. It *doesn't* matter if you move the rectangle at the same time as the circle.
- If the mask is **not** linked to its parent object (the circle)...
  [image]
  ...moving the circle will *not* move the mask. The circle's appearance **will** change as as the circle's position changes. The areas the mask hides *will* change as the circle moves. Again, it *doesn't* matter if you move the rectangle at the same time as the circle.
- Moving the rectangle has no effect on the circle's opacity mask. Even if the rectangle is moved so it would fall *under* the circles mask. The mask will **only** hide parts of the circle, nothing else.

You **can not** move the circle's **mask** *and* the rectangle while keeping the circle in its current position. And you can **not** "group" an opacity mask with anything other than the object it is *applied to*. The mask ***only exists*** for object it is masking - e.g. the circle.

The **only** way to move the circle's mask is to either link it with the circle and move the circle. Or *specifically* click the opacity mask thumbnail on the Transparency Panel and move the mask by itself.

If you need to reposition a mask object in relation to other, unassociated, objects ....

- Select the masked object on the artboard.
- Click the `Release` button on the **Transparency panel**.
- Select the released object(s) and the other object(s) you want to move
- Move things as you want.
- Select the released object(s) and the originally masked object(s).
- Recreate the Opacity Mask for the original object(s).

Comment: Thanks. The issue arised from the fact that I wanted to export my artwork into InDesign, and once you do that, you cannot make changes much. But now I decided to produce my magazine fully in Illustrator, since it will contain lots of graphics. However, I also realized, that making separate masks for each image eliminates the problem. I wanted to create the same mask for all images on the same artboard, and then moving the images + the mask separately would be difficult.

Comment: See my comment to @billy kerr, I explained and added a screenshot.

Comment: Seems to me you may be overcomplicating everything.  What I gather from comments is.. it's all very easily done in InDesign. Illustrator would actually make things *more* difficult. InDesign **frames** essentially act like a mask.. you can blur edges, add gradients, customize the overall shapes, etc - all in InDesign. But, to be honest, I don't "get" the whole "black page" thing. Is your magazine all on black pages? That seems like folly to me. If it's commercially printed, you'll hit ink limits rapidly. If it's home printed, you'll burn through black ink cartridges (or cause your readers to).

Comment: I cannot use brushes in InDesign, so it's not possible to make it solely in InDesign. Yes, the page black is a black fill (not black paper obviously) and almost all pages will have a black background, yes. I thought that it might be a problem for printing, so thanks for the warning. However in magazines you can see pages with black backgrounds, so it's possible.

Comment: I see, checking out the frames, but still cannot use brushes, so it's not possible

Comment: and unlike InDesign, Illustrator has some serious 3D simulation capabilities

Comment: m'kay `:)` Black pages **will** be an issue for commercial printing. You'll want to discuss it with your print provider. If it's just straight black ink, you'll get a dark grey.. if you want it to actually *look* black you'll need a rich black. That's *a lot* of ink coverage. Yes, it's possible, but it takes way more effort (and often money) for printing. There is a difference between an occasional black page and *all* black pages as well. Things get too wet and need to have extra drying time.. slowing down production considerably.

Comment: In short.. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*. `:)`

Comment: I still think you are thinking "backwards" overall. You have a field of black and place *opaque* lighter colored images on top of that. One doesn't create a bunch of "holes" in the black field.

Comment: [Solid (rich) black rectangle in InDesign, then images placed on top of that rectangle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVLHg.png) Text is an AI file with a white stroke and text... image is placed into a custom shaped frame with a `Basic Feather` effect applied to the frame in InDesign. There are no "holes" in the black.

Comment: That is a finite design, meaning that the shapes cannot be altered within InDesign anymore. That's not good. In Illustrator for the text + its background I wouldn't need to import an other file as you needed in InDesign, I can just use a brush and text and be able to modify it anytime. I would only need the mask for the image, and I could easily alter the shape anytime later within Illustrator.

Comment: That's not "finite". I can edit the image or it's frame. I can edit the placed AI document to my heart's content. `:)` You do what you think is best. `:)` My *vast* experience (30+ years) tells me you are on a *bad path* and will regret things later. But I'm not going to try and convince you otherwise if you feel you know better.

Comment: " I can edit the placed AI document to my heart's content. " Yes, but only in AI. I choose Illustrator to be able to make the mag in one app. Thanks.

Comment: Illustrator has limitations compared to InDesign when it comes to text formatting. For a "magazine" that would be the deciding factor here. But good luck to you! I hope works out well!

Comment: superlative effort on this one @Scott...

Comment: Thanks @Kyle `:)` .. although it seems all for naught. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an opacity mask for this.

Instead, create a simple path to use like a masking object, then using that punch out the black background using the pathfinder Minus Front.

Select around the inside path using the Lasso tool (Q), switch to the Selection Too (V) then you can move the cutout with the image.

An example

[image]

Comment: The only reason I needed the clipping in Illustrator is that I wanted to be able to change the colors of the clipped "boxes" in InDesign, by putting a color frame behind them, because \I wanted to create the graphics in Illustrator, and the text in Indesign. But now I decided to finish the whole magazine in Illustrator first, and then move it over to InDesign frame by frame. So I can have live frames and live text in InDesign for my interactive HTML5 ebooks. This is possible because of the new feature that I discovered, that allows me to copy text with formatting between the 2 apps.

Comment: But even though copy pasting text with formatting already works between the 2 apps, the text frame dimensions are still not maintained when pasting. So that's still an issue.

Comment: @AdamAlleman Are you aware that you can place AI files in InDesign, and when you need to edit, you can use Illustrator, and it will update the linked file in InDesign.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I need live frames and live text in InDesign to export the interactive digital HTML5 e-book versions of my publications. And I also need live frames for blend modes. If I blend everything in Illustrator, I cannot have the live frames for my interactive e-book export from Indesign.